# Convert hhhmmss to hh using hive

Tags: hive

i have the data for the below field like below (in hhmmss format)

```
TM
---
930
80
778899
9
99887
```

need to retrieve only HH using hive.

select hour(TM) from t1 gives me null

Comment: values 930,  80, 9, 99887 do not match hhmmss format

Answer (score 0):

Just take a substring:

```
select substr('778899',1,2) --returns '77'
```

You can convert it to integer:

```
select int(substr('778899',1,2))
```